# ASP.NET Core MVC - Is there any way to change the value of specific data on model with session?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Is there any way to change the value of specific data on model?
Like for example my model contains

item_id
item_description
quantity

and you have many records on your data model with the use of session.
on input during changing the quantity i want to update the value on of model with session?
is it recommended? or is there any better way than my approach? thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear. ASP.NET Core is a web app framework, not a data access library. It doesn't have any data models or records. You can modify any object stored in a session or other cache, provided the object itself allows modifications.

Comment: Even if the question was about Entity Framework instead of ASP.NET Core, it would still be unclear. EF doesn't have sessions. A DbContext instance acts the same way a Session would work in Hibernate. Any changes are kept in memory until someone calls `SaveChangesAsync`. Without that call, all changes are discarded

Comment: Sorry for unclear question i'm not really good in english. What I was trying to achieve is to modify the data inside the session. Is modifying data on session also working like a database? where you can get the id and modify the data that  you want?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET Core's Session? Have you [checked the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0) ? Especially the [Get and Set Session Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-and-get-session-values) section. Session is like a dictionary, not a database. You can only look up items by key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I was trying to achieve is to modify the data inside the
> session. Is modifying data on session also working like a database?
> where you can get the id and modify the data that you want?

From your description, I assume you are using Session to the list of records, and now you want to update the session data, right? If that is the case, you could refer to the following sample:

1. Refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to enable the session middleware in the Startup.cs file.

   [Note]: Please remember to set the session expired time via the IdleTimeout property. And, since you are using session to store a list of Objects, remember to add the **SessionExtensions**.

   ```
        //required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
        //required using System.Text.Json;
        public static class SessionExtensions
        {
            public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
            {
                session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
            }

            public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
            {
                var value = session.GetString(key);
                return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
            }
        }
   ```
2. Add an Item View Model:

   ```
    public class ItemViewModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Controller: I'm using a repository to set the Initial data. After getting data from session, we could modify the data, and then, call the set method to save the latest data to the session.

   ```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IDataRepository _repository; 
    public TestController(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataRepository repository)
    {
        _context = context;
        _repository = repository; 
    }

    private readonly string SessionKeyName = "itemlist";
    public IActionResult ItemIndex()
    {
        List<ItemViewModel> items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        //check if the session is exist or not.
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName) == default)
        {   //get the initial data.
            items = _repository.GetItemViewModels();
            //set value to the session.
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName, items);
        }
        else
        {
            items = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName);
        } 
        return  View(items);
    }
    public IActionResult EditItem(int Id)
    {
        List<ItemViewModel> items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        //check if the session is exist or not.
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName) == default)
        {
            items = _repository.GetItemViewModels();
            //set value to the session.
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName, items);
        }
        else
        {
            items = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName);
        }

        return View(items.Where(c=>c.ItemId == Id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditItem(ItemViewModel item)
    {
        List<ItemViewModel> items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
        //check if the session is exist or not.
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName) == default)
        {
            items = _repository.GetItemViewModels();
            //set value to the session.
            HttpContext.Session.Set<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName, items);
        }
        else
        {
            items = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName);
        }

        //based on the primary key to find the special item,
        var i = items.Where(c => c.ItemId == item.ItemId).FirstOrDefault();
        //update the quantity.
        i.Quantity = item.Quantity;
        //Update the session with the latest data.
        HttpContext.Session.Set<List<ItemViewModel>>(SessionKeyName, items);
        //redirect to the ItemIndex action and reload the Index page.
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ItemIndex));
    }
   ```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: oh damn! THANK YOU SO MUCH! <3 You solved my problem!